# Why is /fd/1 (stdout) a socket?

Tags: systemd, socket, file-descriptors, systemd-journald

I'm running a game server as a `systemd` service, and in the `.service` file, I see that StandardOutput defaults to journal.

```shellsession
Ihsan@IhsanServerVM:/proc/28617/fd$ file 1
1: symbolic link to socket:[510374]
```

Then if I check the process file descriptor `1`, `/proc/.../fd/1`, it is a socket.

If I try to read it with `read -u 1`, it does nothing, even though the server is outputting to `stdout`.

Why is it a socket? It should be a named pipe right?

Comment: IIRC pipes don't allow for non-blocking IO.

Comment: @symcbean, why do you think so?

Comment: @ihsan, it's a socket because systemd chooses to implement that as a socket. Possibly due to sockets allowing multiple independent connections, which pipes really don't. If journald just creates one listening socket and then systemd connects to that from each service it starts, all journald has to do is to accept those connections. With pipes, it'd need whole separate pipes for each one.

Comment: @ilkkachu if it is a socket, shouldnt i be able to read it with read command? but it is not reading anything

Comment: @ihsan, no, you can't connect to sockets with `open()`, so the usual command-line tools don't work (including `read`, or `cat`, or such).